# Is it safe to kill vacuumdb?

Tags: postgresql, vacuum

I would like to schedule a vacuumdb cron job for an entire database, but I don't want it to run past a certain time. Is it safe to just stop the job with `killall vacuumdb`?

Comment: Why don't you let the built-in autovacuum do its job?

Comment: If you **really, really** need to do it that way, use [`pg_cancel_backend(pid int)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SIGNAL-TABLE) instead of killing the process.

Comment: What is `autovacuumdb`?  The stock PostgreSQL code doesn't contain such a thing.

Comment: I meant vacuumdb.

Comment: And I don't think that pg_cancel_backend() works on `vacuumdb`, it only works on auto vacuum.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's safe. Use `SIGTERM` (the default, signal 15 on Linux) not `SIGKILL` (signal 9). If it doesn't complete it might waste recent work and have to repeat it.

However, you should really just let autovacuum do its job.

Comment: Autovacuum has got a lot of [parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-autovacuum.html) that can be tuned so that it does not hinder the database normal operation... and so, it can be let to do its job without much effect on overall performance.

Comment: @joanolo but none of the parameters tell it to do the vacuuming when the database is at its least loaded time.  The way the activity-based thresholds work, it is most likely to kick in at the most-loaded time, not the least-loaded time.  So many people intervene to schedule vacuums during off-peak times, for good reasons.

Comment: @jjanes: Agreed, nevertheless... waiting for too long without *analyzing* the data might lead to much worse exeuction plans... which slow down the database no matter what the load.

Comment: @joanolo Right. I'd say the best practice, if you need to schedule manual vacuuming or analyzing, would be to leave autovac turned on.  If your manual processing is sufficient, the auto process will find it has little or nothing to do.  If your manual process is insufficient, you still have a fall back.